# Ghostscript PostScriptTrace related issue

Tags: r, ghostscript

When I run the **R Script** given below, I get the **Error Message** as shown below the R Script. This R Script used to work on my laptop but, it stopped working after re-imaged my laptop. Blank **capturefile1cf05291409.ps** file however, gets created in working directory when I run the script. I don't understand what file/folder I am missing on my laptop. Requesting help to fix this issue.

**The R Script:**

```
library(motifStack)
pcm<-matrix(runif(40,0,100),nrow=4,ncol=10)
pfm<-pcm2pfm(pcm)
rownames(pfm)<-c("A","C","G","T")
motif <- new("pfm", mat=pfm, name="bin_SOLEXA")
plotMotifLogoA(motif)
```

**The Error Message:**

```
Error in PostScriptTrace(paste(psfilename, ".ps", sep = ""), paste(psfilename,  : 
status 127 in running command 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin32c.exe -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOgouvO\filed84397732a4 -sstdout=C:/Users/Tester/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOgouvO/filed844684128f.xml capturefiled844684128f.ps'
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin32c.exe -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOgouvO\filed84397732a4 -sstdout=C:/Users/Tester/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOgouvO/filed844684128f.xml capturefiled844684128f.ps' had status 127
```

**sessionInfo():**

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.2              stringr_1.1.0       ape_4.0             msa_1.6.0           bio3d_2.3-1        
[6] seqinr_3.3-3        shiny_0.14.2        motifStack_1.18.0   Biostrings_2.42.1   XVector_0.14.0     
[11] IRanges_2.8.1       S4Vectors_0.12.1    ade4_1.7-5          MotIV_1.30.0        BiocGenerics_0.20.0
[16] grImport_0.9-0      XML_3.98-1.5       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rsamtools_1.26.1           zlibbioc_1.20.0            bitops_1.0-6              
[4] SummarizedExperiment_1.4.0 lattice_0.20-34            rtracklayer_1.34.1        
[7] htmlwidgets_0.8            GenomicAlignments_1.10.0   GenomicRanges_1.26.1      
[10] xtable_1.8-2               BSgenome_1.42.0            Biobase_2.34.0            
[13] seqLogo_1.40.0             Rcpp_0.12.8                plyr_1.8.4                
[16] tools_3.3.2                RCurl_1.95-4.8             BiocParallel_1.8.1        
[19] nlme_3.1-128               R6_2.2.0                   scales_0.4.1              
[22] digest_0.6.10              mime_0.5                   Matrix_1.2-7.1            
[25] stringi_1.1.2              htmltools_0.3.5            munsell_0.4.3             
[28] rGADEM_2.22.0              colorspace_1.3-2           httpuv_1.3.3              
[31] GenomeInfoDb_1.10.2        magrittr_1.5               yaml_2.1.14               
[34] jsonlite_1.2
```

[image]

Comment: Can you run GhostScript from the command line?

Comment: I don't know how to test GhostScript running it from the command line. any help with this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your R interpreter is attempting to run Ghostscript from "C:\program files\gs\gs9.09\bin", whereas your Windows command line is executing Ghostscript 9.18.

Assuming that you installed a newer version of Ghostscript (using the installer) this means that Ghostscript will be installed in "C:\program files\gs\gs9.18\bin".

You should check to see if you have Ghostscript 9.09 installed and. if not, then you will need to update your R configuration to use the correct directory for GS 9.18.

Comment: I had both instances of GhostScript. I removed the older version. But, still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Well I'd have left the old one, because that's the one your R setup is trying to access..... You will need to re4configure your R setup to use the newer version (no I don't know how to do that). Then you can try running the command line that your R log says is failing. That will either fail, or work. If it fails you can paste the transcript and I may be able to help further. If it works then you'll need someone who understands R to help you further.